# How do I convert a Ruby class name to a underscore-delimited symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

How can I programmatically turn a class name, `FooBar`, into a symbol, `:foo_bar`? e.g. something like this, but that handles camel case properly?

```
FooBar.to_s.downcase.to_sym
```

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Rails comes with a method called `underscore` that will allow you to transform CamelCased strings into underscore_separated strings. So you might be able to do this:

```
FooBar.name.underscore.to_sym
```

But you will have to install ActiveSupport just to do that, as ipsum says.

If you don't want to install ActiveSupport just for that, you can monkey-patch `underscore` into `String` yourself (the underscore function is defined in [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-underscore)):

```
class String
  def underscore
    word = self.dup
    word.gsub!(/::/, '/')
    word.gsub!(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2')
    word.gsub!(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2')
    word.tr!("-", "_")
    word.downcase!
    word
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid this was a Rails extension. :) No worries, as I am actually using Rails.

Comment: Then you should have tagged your question accordingly. Here, let me do it for you...

Comment: No, not ActiveRecord. ActiveSupport.

Comment: @user1406062 open another question for that.

Comment: What about `plus__priced_item` to give `Plus::PricedItem` (namespace involved)? I use `'plus::_priced_items'` but it feels so wrong

Comment: @MrYoshiji please open a different question for that, this question is about underscoring.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for namespaced classes.  Foo::Bar.to_s.underscore becomes foo/bar

Answer (score 85):

**Rails 4 `.model_name`**

In Rails 4, it returns an [`ActiveModel::Name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Name.html) object which contains many useful more "semantic" attributes such as:

```
FooBar.model_name.param_key
#=> "foo_bar"

FooBar.model_name.route_key
#=> "foo_bars"

FooBar.model_name.human
#=> "Foo bar"
```

So you should use one of those if they match your desired meaning, which is likely the case. Advantages:

- easier to understand your code
- your app will still work even in the (unlikely) event that Rails decides to change a naming convention.

BTW, `human` has the advantage of being I18N aware.

Comment: `model_name` also works for instance objects. Ex: `foo_bar.model_name`.
If you want the full list write `foo_bar.model_name.inspect` in rails console or your debugger

Comment: and I was looking for the opposite/reverse, `classify`, `modelize` didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 9):

first: gem install activesupport

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support'
"FooBar".underscore.to_sym
```

Comment: Should be `FooBar.to_s.underscore.to_sym`, since I'm trying to convert a class (which is a constant) into a symbol, which I can then feed to [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl). :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I went for:

```
module MyModule
  module ClassMethods
    def class_to_sym  
      name_without_namespace = name.split("::").last
      name_without_namespace.gsub(/([^\^])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').downcase.to_sym
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end

class ThisIsMyClass
  include MyModule
end 

ThisIsMyClass.class_to_sym #:this_is_my_class
```

Comment: ActiveSupport has `String#demodulize` which will remove the part before `::`.

Comment: @amoebe - thanks for the info. Depends on what your working on though - you may not be working on a rails app (or even a web app).